# GAE with ingress control internal-only

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-tasks

I have an App Engine service with ingress control set internal-only so it is accessible only from google services within the project.

Through a cloud function I create a task to be routed to the App Engine, but when the task is processed by Cloud Tasks Service the error that is generated is that target is 'UNAVAILABLE'.

If I put back ingress control for all, all works correctly. Am I missing something?

Here is the code of the task creation

```html
task = {
    'http_request': {
        'http_method': tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
        'url': url,
    },
  }

  response = client.create_task(request={'parent': parent, 'task': task})
```

Comment: How did you set up the ingress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing it as an Appengine Task instead of an HTTP Target Task?

https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks

So something like this:

```
  task = {
    'app_engine_http_request': {
        'http_method': tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
        'relative_uri': relative_uri,
    },
  }

  response = client.create_task(request={'parent': parent, 'task': task})
```