# GAE service with internal ingress control won't process task

Tags: google-app-engine

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65911327/18265702).  My task creation code is the same as the answer there except that I add a payload.

I have a GAE app with a second service.  I would like this service to have internal ingress only for extra security and I also want this service to process a GAE task.
According to the answer of the linked question, this should work.

When the ingress setting is set to all, everything works fine.  But when the ingress setting is set to internal only, I get a PERMISSION DENIED error.  I've copied the task queue error message below.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

````
{
insertId: "xxx"
jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog"
attemptResponseLog: {
scheduleTime: "2023-12-06T00:06:45.550274Z"
targetType: "APP_ENGINE_HTTP"
maxAttempts: 0
responseCount: "0"
status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
attemptDuration: "0.002211s"
targetAddress: "POST /xxx"
dispatchCount: "1"
}
task: "projects/xxx/locations/us-central1/queues/default/tasks/xxx"
}
logName: "projects/xxx/logs/cloudtasks.googleapis.com%2Ftask_operations_log"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-12-06T00:06:46.807046074Z"
resource: {
labels: {
target_type: "APP_ENGINE_HTTP"
location: "us-central1"
queue_id: "default"
project_id: "xxx"
}
type: "cloud_tasks_queue"
}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2023-12-06T00:06:45.563937621Z"
}```
````

Comment: Have you mentioned the correct stackoverflow link in your question? If yes, can you point out which part of the code you are referring to in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags)? And also have a look at this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65911327/18265702) which might help.

Comment: Hi @SandeepVokkareni, I pasted the wrong link and meant to paste the one in your comment.

Comment: It seems like you are facing an issue with permissions? Can you check whether you have enabled the required permissions as stated in this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference-access-control#roles). You need to remember that each permission is applicable to a particular resource type.

Comment: Hi @minou, Have you managed to check the Cloud Tasks IAM permissions?

Comment: Also are you using cloud tasks with VPC connections?

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni, I haven't tried updating permissions yet but will do that.  It is a GAE task and not an HTTP target task.  I do have a VPC because I also have a reddis instance.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comments, It seems like you are facing an issue with permissions? Can you check whether you have enabled the required permissions as stated in this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference-access-control#roles). You need to remember that each permission is applicable to a particular resource type.

Also as you confirmed that you have a VPC connection, It seems Cloud Tasks do not support VPC connections (Internal access to GAE) currently. This is because Cloud Tasks runs in a Google Managed project outside your VPC.

To use Cloud Tasks with VPC network, there is already a feature request filed for it as you can refer to the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/154481516) and you can mark `+1` or add your concern over there.

As a work around for now, you can try to create HTTP Target tasks with the load balancer endpoint instead of GAE endpoint in Cloud Tasks by referring to [link](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks). Please be aware that since this solution uses public internet via Load Balancing, it will incur extra charges of [Load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#lb).